# How to delete a specific text file (based on name) in TCL after searching all folders, not just the current directory?

Tags: tcl

How do I search for a particular file name in the entire directory and then delete it in TCL?

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is using the [`fileutil::traverse`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/traverse.md) package from tcllib, which safely searches a directory tree for matching files. You can then call [`file delete`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M12) with those filenames.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require fileutil::traverse

# Look for all foo.txt files regardless of directory.
# Use this to get the OS-specific path delimiter instead of a hardcoded / or \\
set pattern [file join * foo.txt]
fileutil::traverse findFoo . -filter [list string match $pattern]
# I suggest a dry run first to make sure your filter is returning just the
# appropriate filename(s).
puts [findFoo files]
# When satisfied, delete for real.
# file delete [findFoo files]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the easiest way, although it is not portable:

```
puts [exec find . -name $filenameToDelete -print]
```

If that find the right files, you can do this

```
exec find . -name $filenameToDelete -delete
```